# Android :How to Implement Single Sign On (SSO) for GMAIL on MyApp?

Tags: android, gmail, single-sign-on

I want to integrate GMAIL Single Sign on (SSO) on my App.. I am not getting the library for Gmail. Please Anyone can help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try out This Link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-a/2033124#2033124

Comment: You need to clarify: what kind of access to you want: read/send? Where do you need this access: android or GAE?

Comment: @PeterKnego -- only Reading the Gmail & Authenticating Users in Mobile Apps. I want to access in my android mobile App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this link
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps

**Authenticating Users in Mobile Apps**

Many web applications have companion mobile applications, such as native Android and iOS apps. These native applications typically ask the user for their email address and password to authenticate them. This method of authentication will not work when the web application has a complex login system which uses technologies like OpenID or SAML for federated authentication. In this guide, we'll describe an alternative technique to enable mobile applications to work for all users, regardless of how they are authenticated.

If you're anxious to see how this works, you can check out the Demo and Sample Code section at the bottom of this page.

Comment: I ll try to implement & let you know the result.. Thank you